# Find kibana api uri and port

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have access to elasticsearch indices via some space in kibana visualization
**Its not on my localhost, its some remote host**

I am trying to get "api" endpoint that I can potentially use in python/curl to do get requests and further scripting

My kibana url is in this fashion

```
https://<host-name>/insights/k/<workspace_or_something>/s/<some_space_name>/app/home#/
```

I tried inspect , dev console, but I can not find API URI which I can use "basic" user/password based auth

Thanks